# spark submit fails when extra classpath is given for jars that are in hdfs location

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I am running my spark job as yarn client mode for which, 
I need guava jar for my spark job that needs to be in driver and executors classpath.

So, I am running below spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --class "com.bk.App" --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-cores 2  --driver-memory 1G --driver-cores 1 --driver-class-path /home/my_account/spark-jars/guava-19.0.jar  --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/my_account/spark-jars/guava-19.0.jar maprfs:///user/my_account/jobs/spark-jobs.jar parma1 parma2
```

which give me below exception:

```
Downloading maprfs:///user/my_account/jobs/spark-jobs.jar to /tmp/tmp732578642370806645/user/my_account/jobs/spark-jobs.jar.
2018-10-29 19:37:52,2025 ERROR JniCommon fs/client/fileclient/cc/jni_MapRClient.cc:566 Thread: 6832 Client initialization failed due to mismatch of libraries. Please make sure that the java library version matches the native build version 5.0.0.32987.GA and native patch version $Id: mapr-version: 5.0.0.32987.GA 40889:3056362e419b $
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Could not create FileClient
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:593)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.lookupClient(MapRFileSystem.java:654)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getMapRFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:1310)
    at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.getFileStatus(MapRFileSystem.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:297)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2066)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2035)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2011)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.downloadFile(SparkSubmit.scala:874)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$1.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:316)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I even tried putting my guava jar to hdfs location and added extra classpath using `hdfs://` and even `maprfs://` in my spark submit. Tried giving `local://` too. All end up in same above exception.

Note: Job works absolutely fine, if no driver and executor extra classpath jars are given.

Any suggestions? am I using the class path param in wrong way?